# Find the spectral density of the square of white noise with a limited bandwidth

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density, white-noise

I tried the following order of operations:

Let's consider the spectral density of the square of white noise with
with a limited frequency band. If $S_{x} \! \left( f \right)$ is the spectral density of white noise then $S_{y} \! \left( f \right)$ is the spectral density of the square of this noise. For band-limited white noise, the spectral density of the power $S_{x} \! \left( f \right)$ is constant between $-B$ and $B$ and is equal to $N_{0}$ (spectral power per unit frequency). Then the power spectral density of a square of white noise with a limited frequency band is written as follows:

$$ S_{y} \! \left( f \right) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} S_{x} \! \left( \omega \right) * S_{x} \! \left( f - \omega \right) d \omega \tag{1} $$

Substituting the value for $S_{x} \! \left( \omega \right) = N_{0}$ in the range from $-B$ to $B$, we obtain:

$$ S_{y} \! \left( f \right) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} = \int_{-B}^{B} N_{0} * N_{0} \, d \omega \tag{2} $$

Simplifying the integral we obtain:

$$ S_{y} \! \left( f \right) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} N_{0}^{2} 2 B = \frac{N_{0}^{2} B}{\pi} \tag{3} $$

But that answer is wrong.

Comment: Hi, welcome to DSP.SE! Please typeset your equations using $\LaTeX$ rather than adding pictures of your Maths. As for your question the integral you are trying to solve is a **convolution** integral. What you should actually solve for is:

$$S_y(f) = \frac{N_0^2}{2\pi} \int_{-B}^{B} \mathbb{1}_{\{ |f-\omega| \leq B \}} \, d\omega $$

where $\mathbb{1}$ is the indicator function, which is 1 if $|f-\omega| \leq B$ and 0 otherwise. This integral effectively counts the overlap between two bandwidths centered at $f $ and $\omega$, respectively, both with a bandwidth of $2B$.

Comment: You know that the answer you came up with is wrong. Do you have the correct solution? If so, please add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

We should take this step by step. Let's say we have a noise signal $n(t)$ and it's Fourier Transform $N(\omega)$

Squaring in the time domain is multiplication with itself.

$$q(t) = n^2(t)  = n(t) \cdot n(t) \tag{1}$$

Multiplication in time is equivalent to convolution in the frequency domain

$$Q(\omega) = N(\omega) * N(\omega) \tag{2}$$

where $*$ is the convolution operator.

The power spectral density is the magnitude squared of the spectrum

$$S_q(\omega) = |Q(\omega)|^2 = |N(\omega) * N(\omega)|^2 \tag{3}$$

So it's NOT the convolution of the PSD of itself, but you have to convolve the spectra and then square that result to get the final PSD.